# ¿Cómo se pude crear una validación con condicionales donde si un numero dado no es múltiplo de 10.000 me arroje un aviso de error?

Tags: python

Hago un algoritmo en Python de un cajero para retirar dinero, necesito que si se pide retirar un valor que no es múltiplo de 10.000 arroje el  aviso:

“Digita una cantidad valida, {valor} no es aceptado”. En caso de que ingrese una cantidad que no sea múltiplo de 10.000

Se me ocurre hacer una función donde el valor a retirar se divida entre 10.000. Y si el resultado de la división es una cifra decimal o de tipo float me dispare el aviso de error.

```
def validacion_multiplo10k(valor_ingresado):
    resultado_validacion =valor_ingresado/10000
    if resultado_validacion == 
    return f Digita una cantidad valida, {valor_ingresado} no es aceptado”.

print(validacion_multiplo10k(155000))
```

Algunos me aconsejan que haga un módulo aparte verificando la cantidad de los billetes, la verdad no sé cómo hacerlo.
Gracias

Comment: if valor_ingresado % 10000 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

Comment: La condición de no ser múltiplo de 10.000 la puedes revisa con `if valor_ingresado % 10_000:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para encontrar el múltiplo de un numero, debemos dividir ese numero por la cantidad que ingresamos, y de esa manera si la división es exacta el numero sera multiplo de ese numero. la condicion seria if valor % 10.000 == 0: entramos a la condicion.

```
def multiplo(num):
    if num % 10000 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

valor_ingresado = 55000
aux = multiplo(valor_ingresado)

if not aux:
    print("Digita una cantidad valida, "+ str(valor_ingresado) +" no es aceptado")

else:
    print("Has digitado una cantidad valida")
```

Definimos nuestra funcion que devuelve un booleano, si es multiplo devuelve true, sino false, luego ese valor que devuelve, if/si no es true mandamos un mensaje de error, sino indicamos que ha digitado una cantidad valida.

Espero te sirva mi solución.